# What is the quadratic function whose only root is -3 and whose graph goes through the point (-2, 5)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From the problem I can gather that:

$$ b^2-4ac = 0$$
$$ -\frac{b}{2a} = -3$$
$$ 5 = (-2)^2a -2b + c$$

The answer to the problem is $f(x)=5(x+3)^2$, and I can't arrive to that answer...

Are my equations correct?

Comment: The quadratic will be of form $f(x)=A(x-a)(x-b)=A(x+3)^2$. put $x$ and find $A$.

Comment: "$5 = (-2)^2 -2b + c$"  Not quite.  You know $5 = (-2)^2a -2b + c$.  Now you should have enough info.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli yes I made a mistake in typing it out, that's what I was using

Comment: @fleablood yes I'm sorry, I made a mistake typing that as well. That's what I used

Comment: Those equations are correct, and will work, although as pointed out, there are faster ways.

Comment: @Arthur thank you, that was what I was worried about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a bunch of formula think about it graphically. As it has a double root at $(-3,0)$ then it must be of the form:

$y=a(x+3)^2$

Then use the second bit of information to solve for $a$.

$5=a(-2+3)^2$

$5=a$

So the equation is $y=5(x+3)^2$

Edit:

Your equations are correct. You haven't provided your attempt so I'm not sure what you did wrong. Here is how I'd solve them.

From second one: $b=6a$

Sub this into the first: $36a^2-4ac=0$

As $a\neq0$ then we have $c=9a$

Sub these into the third to get: $5=4a-12a+9a$

Which gives $a=5$

Hence $b=30$ and $c=45$.

So $f(x)=5x^2+30x+45=5(x^2+6x+9)=5(x+3)^2$

Comment: I see... That makes sense and it's a lot easier. Are my equations correct though?